# graficos en unvotes

Tags: r

Cómo puedo elaborar un gráfico de barras con el resultado de una pregunta formulada dentro de un_votes? ¿Cómo cuántos votos se obtendrán dependiendo del tema? el resultado que obtuve es:

issue                                    n
                                
1 Arms control and disarmament          1092
2 Palestinian conflict                  1061
3 Human rights                          1015
4 Colonialism                            957
5 Nuclear weapons and nuclear material   855
6 Economic development                   765

> 

Alguien que me pueda guiar?

por_problema%>%ggplot(aes(x=problema,y=n)

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que no tenemos acceso a la data para ayudar de manera más precisa. El ejemplo a continuación (creado a partir de datos falsos) puede dar una respuesta a lo que estas buscando:

Primero necesitas agrupar los votos según cada problemas, para lo cual puedes utilzar la función `group_by`, y el resultado lo incorporas como parte de la función de `ggplot`.

```
## Fake data
DF <- tibble(`problemas` = rep(c("problema_1", "problema_2", "problema_3"), 7),
             `num_votos` = as.integer(rep(c("123", "434","234"), 7)))

## Crear gráfico por problemas

DF %>% 
  group_by(problemas) %>% 
  summarize(total_votos = sum(num_votos)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = problemas, y = total_votos)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]